# How to generate array of n equidistant points along a line segment of length x?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, coordinates, line, point

I ported this function from a python answer to a similar question on this site.  However, although the points are equidistant from each other, they are not centered on the line.

The first point is at `0` while the last is at `83` (the end of the line segment is `100`).

How do I center this row of points?

Specifically, I want the first point to be the same distance from `0` that the last point is from `100`.

```js
'use strict';

function generatePoints(count, length) {
  const points = []
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    const a = i / count;
    const x = a * length;
    points.push(Math.round(x));
  }
  return points;
}

const points = generatePoints(6, 100);

console.log(points);
// [ 0, 17, 33, 50, 67, 83 ]
```

I tried this, but it doesn't appear to work as I expected:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
  points[i] += (points[1] / 2);
  points[i] = Math.round(points[i]);
}

console.log(points);
// [ 9, 26, 46, 63, 80, 96 ]
```

The first point is `9` away from `0`, but the last point is `4` away from `100`.

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: For instance, `[ 2, 4, 6, 8 ]`.  All points are equidistant from each other, AND from the ends of the line segment reaching from `0` to `10`.  But the function I need should accept the line length (`10` here) as a parameter, and the number of points as a parameter also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `i / count` to `(i + 1) / (count + 1)`.